# Value changes when returned in an Angular 1.x Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a really weird problem with Angular and wondering if anyone has encountered this.

```
var transformResponse = function(data) {
    var jobs = data.job.map(convertResponseToJob);
    console.log(jobs);
    // return jobs;
}
```

This logs the correct array with all the values within it, but this logs an array of the same length with undefined as each value.

```
var transformResponse = function(data) {
    var jobs = data.job.map(convertResponseToJob);
    console.log(jobs);
    return jobs;
}
```

This may be something really obvious as I haven't worked with Angular factories very much, but I couldn't find an explanation.

Other Functions:

```
     function convertResponseToJob(response){
            var jobObj = new Job(response.id, response.clientId, response.book);
            jobObj.bookName = response.book.name;
            jobObj.submitDate = response.createDate;
            jobObj.priority = response.priority;
            jobObj.status = response.status;
            jobObj.sequence = response.seqOrder;
            return jobObj;
        }


        function Job(jobId, client, book) {
            this.jobId = jobId;
            this.client =  client;
            this.book = book;
            this.bookName = null;
            this.submitDate = null;
            this.priority = 2;
            this.sequence = 2;
            this.status = null;
        }
```

Comment: where do you get `data` from?

Comment: Sorry, data is a parameter of the function. I'll update that.

Comment: I think your problem comes from `convertResponseToJob` could you share it's code?

Comment: Added, though I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using  `response.data` instead? Your raw response may not be an array.

Comment: The transform response function works perfectly as long as I don't return the value. When it's commented out, that console.log gives me exactly what I need. When it's not, the value changes, which seems strange to me since the return happens after the log.

Comment: That's because when you don't return you don't change the response. What's in the `data` object?

Comment: Maybe setup a plunker?

Comment: But anything that happens as a result of the 'return' would happen after the log, so why would it affect what is logged?

Comment: try introducing some global variable and assign to it `jobs[0]`

Comment: If I assign jobs[0] to a variable and return that variable, I am able to return the correct variable and the console.log is correct.

Comment: if you don't use `console.log`, does it break something in your code? is `console.log` the issue?

Comment: No the code breaks without it, because the array it returns is read as undefined.

Comment: can you reproduce this on a fiddle ?

Comment: I don't seem to be having any such side-effects.  This is also not to do with variable hoisting or prototypical inheritance or execution contexts.  Not even closure related issue.  I [created this plunk and works fine printing](http://plnkr.co/edit/vEZMpdHENgrVISAik8Jb?p=preview) out array with elements in both cases.

Comment: Yea, it's definitely not a vanilla javascript issue. It has something to do with the Angular factory and it returning a promise.